# How to use image in pdf

Tags: php, laravel

I used laravel-pdf (https://github.com/niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf) package.
I want to use img tag in my PDF view.

My controller code:

```php
public function generatePdf()
{
    $pdf= Pdf::loadView('resume::resumePdf', compact('resume'));
    return $pdf->stream('document.pdf');
}
```

My view:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fa" dir="rtl">
<head>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <style>
            body {
                font-family: persianfont;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
</head>

<body>

</body>
   <img id="resumeProfileImage" src="url('/images/avatar.png')" width="100" height="100"/>
</html>
```

When I run this code, no show error, just is loading.

Answer (score 2):

**Use**

```
<img src="'. public_path() .'/images/avatar.png">
```

Comment: Thank you so much for guide me @TamirKlein because of its simple use of blade file to view image.

Comment: please select this answer if its help for you THANK YOU!! @mohammad nabipour

Comment: What do you mean by public_path()؟

Answer (score 0):

You should encode the image to base64 first. First, you need to get raw image first using `file_get_contents('/images/avatar.png')` or `Storage::get('/images/avatar.png')` or something other, then you encode it to base64 using `base64_encode()` function

Example code

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, {!! base64_encode(file_get_contents('/images/avatar.png')) !!}" width="100" height="100">
```